# Different results on printing the values of array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, for-loop, plpgsql, postgresql-9.4

I am writing a stored procedure that accepts a string as an input and then converts that string to an array with comma as a delimiter, once I have that array I am appending a string '_1' to each element of the array as I need to further utilize that. However when I execute this stored proc to find the result the raise info command behaves differently on printing the value of array (the values will change obviously but the format in which they are displayed changes)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Test1(inputlist text) RETURNS text AS $BODY$
DECLARE
a text;
acceptList text[];
counter integer;
length integer;
BEGIN
acceptList = string_to_array(inputList,',');

SELECT array_length(acceptList,1) into length;

RAISE INFO 'Length : %',length;
RAISE INFO 'AcceptList Print 1 : %',acceptList;
counter = 0;
FOREACH a in ARRAY acceptList LOOP
    acceptList[counter] = a||'_1';
    counter = counter + 1;
    END LOOP;
RAISE INFO 'AcceptList Print 2 : %',acceptList;
END;
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The output in messages tab would be :

```
INFO:  Length : 4
INFO:  AcceptList Print 1 : {INC000073535133,INC000073533828,INC000073535942,INC000073535857}
INFO:  Acceptlist Print 2 : [0:4]={INC000073535133_1,INC000073533828_1,INC000073535942_1,INC000073535857_1,INC000073535857}
```

If you notice in the above output the values are appended correctly however, in the print 2 it is showing the size as well as an equal to symbol before printing the values of array

Want to understand why such behavior is seen

Comment: You don't need a function, a loop or even PL/pgSQL for that. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9e2ef65f920bd4048446548af3387daa

Comment: I know, it could be done outside of SQL but if done within, why the format of info messages is different

Answer (score 0):

By default, arrays in Postgres are indexed from 1, while in the function body the first index of the modified array is 0. As a result, the original array has been extended by one element. The notation `[0:4] = {...}` means a five-element array with the non-standard first index of 0. Of course, this could be fixed in a simple way:

```sql
...
counter = 1;
FOREACH a in ARRAY acceptList LOOP
...
```

However, note the comment by horse_with_no_name that indicated how this should be done in Postgres with a single query:

```sql
select string_agg(concat(t.element, '_1'), ',' order by t.nr) 
from unnest(string_to_array('one,two,three',',')) with ordinality as t(element, nr);
```

Read about arrays in [the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html)